# using django variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, django

My Models:

```
class Category(models.Model):    
    category_name=models.CharField(max_length = 100)  
    def __str__(self):  
        return self.Category_name  
class Song(models.Model):  
    category= models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  
    pass
```

```html
<body>
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'home/index.css' %}" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function printSong(x){
        var all = {{x.song_set.all}};
        document.getElementById("main");
        var them = [{% for song in all %}{{song.song_name}}{% endfor %}];
    main.innerHTML = them;
    }
</script>
<header>
    <h2 id="NSM" title="Nigeria Sheet Music">NSM</h2>
    <p id="welcome"> Welcome {{user.username}}</p>
    <div class="scrollmenu">
        {% for song in all_category %}
        <a href="# " id="{{song.category_name}}" onclick="printSong('{{ song.category_name }}')">{{song.category_name}}</a>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</header>
<div id="left">
    <p>playing</p>
</div>
<div id="right">
    <p id="songHeading"> Your Songs    <p id="add"><a href="{% url 'home:song-add' %}">add song</a></p> </p>
    {% for song in user.song_set.all %}
    <div class="songBack">
        <a href="{% url 'home:detail' song.id %}">
            {{song.song_name}} </li>
            <a href="#">  edit</a>
            <a href="#">  delete</a>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
</body>
```

I was wondering how to include `django` variable in JavaScript file. I created two models Category and song , I linked song to category with foreign key. I was trying to write a code in JavaScript so that when a category is selected ,all the songs in the category will be displayed

Comment: Show your models, current template, and current JavaScript code, and describe what's not working.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How to include django variable in JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

If you can display the songs via json, you could use Ajax. Something a bit like this (I put this together just before seeing your code so the model names etc are different, but as an example):

```
function getSongs(category) {
    $.ajax({
    url : "songs/", // links to a django view to get the songs
    type : "POST",
    data : { id }, // you could take the category id from the template eg {{ category.id }}
    dataType : 'json',

    success : function(songs) {
    // an example of getting song titles
    for (i = 0; i < songs.length; i++) {
        song = songs[i]
        title = song.title
        // do something with the title here
        }
    }
  }) 
}
```

And on the view at 'songs'

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from models import Category

def songs(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        category_id = request.POST.get('id')
        category = Category.objects.get(id=category_id)
        songs = category.songs.all()
        jsonSongs = []
        for song in songs:
             jsonSong = {}
             jsonSong["title"] = song.title
             // title used here just to show how you might access aspects of the song model
             jsonSongs.append(jsonSong)
    return JsonResponse(songs, safe=False)
```

From here you could access a list of songs as json objects.